What did St. Gregory of Nazianzus mean by forbidden knowledge and the need to conceal knowledge gained within the Church?
In Oration 40, towards the end, a translation from newadvent.org is as follows:

But not yet perhaps is there formed upon your soul any writing good or
bad; and you want to be written upon today, and formed by us unto
perfection. Let us go within the cloud. Give me the tables of your
heart; I will be your Moses, though this be a bold thing to say; I
will write on them with the finger of God a new Decalogue. Exodus
38:28 I will write on them a shorter method of salvation. And if there
be any heretical or unreasoning beast, let him remain below, or he
will run the risk of being stoned by the Word of truth. I will baptize
you and make you a disciple in the Name of the Father and of the Son
and of the Holy Ghost; and These Three have One common name, the
Godhead. And you shall know, both by appearances Matthew 28:19 and by
words that you reject all ungodliness, and are united to all the
Godhead. Believe that all that is in the world, both all that is seen
and all that is unseen, was made out of nothing by God, and is
governed by the Providence of its Creator, and will receive a change
to a better state. Believe that evil has no substance or kingdom,
either unoriginate or self-existent or created by God; but that it is
our work, and the evil one's, and came upon us through our
heedlessness, but not from our Creator. Believe that the Son of God,
the Eternal Word, Who was begotten of the Father before all time and
without body, was in these latter days for your sake made also Son of
Man, born of the Virgin Mary ineffably and stainlessly (for nothing
can be stained where God is, and by which salvation comes), in His own
Person at once entire Man and perfect God, for the sake of the entire
sufferer, that He may bestow salvation on your whole being, having
destroyed the whole condemnation of your sins: impassible in His
Godhead, passible in that which He assumed; as much Man for your sake
as you are made God for His. Believe that for us sinners He was led to
death; was crucified and buried, so far as to taste of death; and that
He rose again the third day, and ascended into heaven, that He might
take you with Him who were lying low; and that He will come again with
His glorious Presence to judge the quick and the dead; no longer
flesh, nor yet without a body, according to the laws which He alone
knows of a more godlike body, that He may be seen by those who pierced
Him, Revelation 1:7 and on the other hand may remain as God without
carnality. Receive besides this the Resurrection, the Judgment and the
Reward according to the righteous scales of God; and believe that this
will be Light to those whose mind is purified (that is, God — seen and
known) proportionate to their degree of purity, which we call the
Kingdom of heaven; but to those who suffer from blindness of their
ruling faculty, darkness, that is estrangement from God, proportionate
to their blindness here. Then, in the tenth place, work that which is
good upon this foundation of dogma; for faith without works is dead,
James 2:17 even as are works apart from faith. This is all that may be
divulged of the Sacrament, and that is not forbidden to the ear of the
many. The rest you shall learn within the Church by the grace of the
Holy Trinity; and those matters you shall conceal within yourself,
sealed and secure.

At the end of this paragraph there is a reference to knowledge only gained after initiation into the Church, and of the need to conceal that knowledge. What could St. Gregory have been talking about? I noticed that in this creed of sorts Gregory does not talk about Communion - could it be that the Eucharist, and the mystery of eating the flesh of Christ, was the mystery that Christians could not speak about to outsiders/the uninitiated?
The one reference I have found in that oration to the Eucharist is a somewhat vague

Remember how poor you once were, and how rich you were made. One in
want of bread or of drink, perhaps another Lazarus, is cast at your
gate; respect the Sacramental Table to which you have approached, the
Bread of Which you have partaken, the Cup in Which you have
communicated, being consecrated by the Sufferings of Christ.

As this oration appears to be directed to those about to undergo the Sacrament of Baptism, this could still fit in with my theory that the true "trans-subtantiated" nature of the Bread and Cup that is celebrated before the Sacramental Table is only revealed to the initiated.
A further side note or post scriptum - what does St. Gregory mean by the "Festival on the illustrious Day of the Holy Lights"?

As with any old text, context in history is vital. Let's have a look.


St. Gregory the Theologian, Oration 40
Subject: Baptism, and the benefits that come to us from it.
Target Audience: Catechumens and their catechists.


Historical context: After 4 decades of Arian bishops, this new bishop "imposed" by the new emperor is preaching. So it is likely that the Catechumens might have had some "concerns" about if the new bishop was "orthodox" and "acceptable".
Looking at the orations. It is clear he is attempting to address a deeply ingrained  inclination to postpone sacramental initiation until the last possible moment. We can see this in the previous oration as well.

“Where there is purification there is illumination,” Gregory explains. “And illumination is the fulfillment of desire for those who aim for the greatest things, or that which is greater, or that which is beyond greatness” (Oration 39.8).

So he gives them 5 different kinds of baptism (Oration 39)

The figurative Baptism of Israel by Moses in the cloud and in the Sea.
The preparatory Baptism of repentance ministered by S. John the Baptist.
The spiritual Baptism of water and the Holy Ghost given us by our Lord.
The glorious Baptism of Martyrdom.
The painful Baptism of Penance.

And then we get 10 articles of the Faith:

The Trinity
God the Father almighty created heaven and earth, all things visible and invisible
God did not create evil
The Incarnation of the Eternal Word of the Holy Spirit and the Virgin Mary, and the hypostatic union
His crucifixion, death and burial
His bodily resurrection
His ascension
His bodily second coming
The Last Judgment, with proportionate rewards and punishments [not just simple heaven and hell]
The necessity of good works, for “faith without works is dead, even as are works apart from faith.” [no consideration of forensic imputation, which does not appear in Christian theology until the 16h century].

And then we get to your question "The rest you shall learn within the Church by the grace of the Holy Trinity; and those matters you shall conceal within yourself, sealed and secure."
In the old church (unlike the more strictly rational modern western churches) you were expected to experience and receive spiritual knowledge through your relationship with God. But this was not generally considered something to keep hidden.
Ultimately, I believe the subject here is actually found in "The Order of Preparation for Holy Communion"

Of Thy Mystical Supper, O Son of God, receive me today as a
communicant; for I will not speak of the Mystery to Thine enemies; nor
will I give Thee a kiss, as did Judas, but like the thief do I confess
Thee: Remember me, O Lord, in Thy kingdom.

So I believe you are correct in thinking that St. Gregory is referring to the sacrament of the Divine Liturgy//Eucharist.
Your side question is more easily answered. "Festival on the illustrious Day of the Holy Lights."

Yesterday we kept high Festival on the illustrious Day of the Holy Lights. (40.19

St. Gregory of Nazianzus seemed to enjoy using very elaborate and colorful descriptions that are not inaccurate, just more than we are used to today.
For example "The Feast of God's Appearing" was "The Nativity"
In this case, Jan 6th is for "Theophany". ALthough Jan 6th was I believe at the time a combination of Nativity and Epiphany (they were not separate until the late 4th century AD) (For more detail about such things see here)
So what is the night before?

With the end of the persecutions, the contents of these events were developed in the observance of the feast of Epiphany which is called the Feast of Lights. (goarch website on Epiphany

That is to say, the Baptism of Jesus. (What better day to preach on the benefits of Baptism?)
